# Unable to fetch web elements in pytest-bdd behave in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation

So, I'm in the middle of creating a test-automation framework using pytest-bdd and behave in python 3.10.

I have some codes, but the thing is, I'm not able to fetch the web element from the portal. The error doesn't say anything about it. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl8Ge.jpg) is the error I'm getting in the console.

Let me share the codes here too for better understanding.

demo.feature

```
Feature: Simple first feature

  @test1
  Scenario: Very first test scenario
    Given Launch Chrome browser
    When open my website
    Then verify that the logo is present
    And close the browser
```

test_demo.py

```
from behave import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then

import time

import variables
import xpaths
from pages.functions import *
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


# @scenario('../features/demo.feature', 'Very first test scenario')
# def test_eventLog():
#     pass


@given('Launch Chrome browser')
def given_launchBrowser(context):
    launchWebDriver(context)
    print("DEBUG >> Browser launches successfully.")


@when('Open my website')
def when_openSite(context):
    context.driver.get(variables.link)
    # context.driver.get(variables.nitsanon)
    print("DEBUG >> Portal opened successfully.")


@then('verify that the logo is present')
def then_verifyLogo(context):
    time.sleep(5)
    status = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpaths.logo_xpath)
    # status = findElement(context, xpaths.logo_xpath)
    print('\n\n\n\n', status, '\n\n\n\n')
    assert status is True, 'No logo present'
    print("DEBUG >> Logo validated successfully.")

@then('close the browser')
def then_closeBrowser(context):
    context.driver.close()
```

variables.py

```
link = 'https://nitin-kr.onrender.com/'
```

xpaths.py

```
logo_xpath = "//*[@id='logo']/div"
```

requirements.txt

```
behave~=1.2.6
selenium~=4.4.3
pytest~=7.1.3
pytest-bdd~=6.0.1
```

> Let me know if you need any more information. I'm very eager to create an automation testing framework without any OOPs concept used.

Just the thing is, I'm not able to fetch the web elements. Not able to use find_element(By.XPATH, XPATH).send_keys(VALUE) like methods of selenium.